# Freeze Slicers in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Hi I am trying to freeze slicers such that when you scroll down the pivot table will scroll but the slicers to the right of the pivot table remain in a fixed position. I figure I would use a freeze pain but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone wondering. I figured out if you do freeze top row and put the slicers in the top row it will work vertically but not horizontally. Vice versa if you freeze a col and put the slicers in the column it will work horizontally but not vertically.

Thus,

Click View -> Freeze Pane -> Freeze Top row or Freeze Top Coll

Then make the row or column as big as you need to fit your slicers in.